# How to write correct jest test for this code?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

My codes are：

utils.js:

```
exports.a = function a(){
 b()
}
function b() {}
exports.b = function b(){
}
```

utils.test.js:

```
var utils = require('./utils')
test('b called by a', () => {
  u.b = jest.fn()

  utils.a()
  expect(utils.b).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

When run unit test,it failed with:

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

How to test it in a correct way?

Comment: You have two `b` function, `a` function use the one that is not exported. You replace the `b` which is exported not used by `a`. Does your code correct?

Comment: Testing for a function to have been called should be a last resort for how to test a function. Look at what are your inputs into the system and the expected outputs/side-effects/state/behavior you need to see to know that the system is working. The next developer on the team is going to change _how_ the functionality is implemented; they want your tests to assure them that the basic functionality still works, not that a certain method was called.